# git ignore all files, except those of a type, expect ignore one file of a type, by updating .gitignore in existing repo

Tags: git, gitignore

I'm trying to create a .gitignore that can:

- Ignore all files
- Except don't ignore all files that end in .inc
- Except DO ignore one specific file, some_file.inc

This doesn't seem to work, although I'm altering a .gitignore for an existing repo which was already committed and pushed.

Now I realize I don't want to track changes to a certain file that the repo was tracking. When I pull down later on this repo, I don't want any changes for this particular file to come down. I also don't need detect changes to this file with 'git status' or have to commit them before pulling down.

```
# Ignore Everything
*

# Except don't ignore *.inc files
!*.inc

# Except ignore some_file.inc?
some_file.inc
```

What can I do to accomplish this?

Comment: *When I pull down later on this repo, I don't want any changes for this particular file to come down.* You can't get this, because Git doesn't store *changes* in the first place. Git stores whole snapshots. Every commit is a full snapshot of all of its files. The `git pull` command means (1) fetch new commits; then (2) run `git merge` to *modify* what you have now to *incorporate* the new commits you fetched. To stop modifying a file that *someone else* has put into a commit, you will need to change strategies.

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks for the link ... git update-index --skip-worktree <file> worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

`.gitignore` does not apply to files that are already tracked (committed).

In order to stop tracking them, a commit that explicitly deletes these file needs to be created.

Any commits after that will stop tracking those files you want to `.gitignore`